Ingress nginx routes to last wildcard and ignores precedence
I have the following ingress service config:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /backend
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-svc
                port:
                  number: 4000
            pathType: Prefix
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: web-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
            pathType: Prefix

and I forward the port so I can access the cluster through localhost:3000, but it looks like when I try to access localhost:3000/backend, I routed to the web-svc and get a 404 status code and not routed to the backend-svc as expected. When I remove the reference to the web-svc, though, I'm able to be routed to the backend service just fine. How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Changing - path: /?(.*)  to  - path: /.* , you are ensuring that the path/backend will not be matched by the generic .* pattern, and thus it will be routed specifically to the backend-svc. This change should resolve the issue you're encountering.

Currently, the path /?(.*) is matching all paths, including /backend, which is why requests to /backend are being routed to web-svc.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-svc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /backend
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-svc
                port:
                  number: 4000
            pathType: Prefix
          - path: /.*
            backend:
              service:
                name: web-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
            pathType: Prefix

With this configuration, requests to /backend will be routed to backend-svc, and all other paths will be routed to web-svc.
